# Java warning - JList is a raw type, references must be parameterized

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jlist

Can someone shed more light the following warning from Eclipse:

`JList is a raw type. References to generic type JList<E> should be parameterized.`

A line of code triggering this could be:

```
import javax.swing.JList;
....
private JList jList = null;  // Warning on this line
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put the type of the elements between <>, for example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("String 1");
list.add("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 3):

JList is a raw type as of Java 1.7, the same goes for a couple more of swing components.  Your x86 and x64_86 enviroments probably have diferent versions of java, that's why you're getting the warning in one, and no warning in the other.