# Split string in Java and append to list

Tags: java, jlist

Use case: I am trying to xtract the arguments inside the parenthesis and populate it to a jList.

Input:

```
title(a1, a3)
```

Code:

```
    static ArrayList variableList = new ArrayList();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(result.toString().trim());
    while(m.find()) 
     { 
        if (!variableList.contains(m.group(1).trim()))
        { 
        variableList.add(m.group(1).trim());
        }
     }

    DefaultListModel lista1 = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0;i<variableList.size();i++)
     {
        if (!lista1.contains(variableList.get(i)))
        {
        lista1.addElement(variableList.get(i));
        }
    }

    jList.setModel(lista1);  
    revalidate();
    repaint();
```

Expected Output in jList:

[image]

Code Output:

[image]

The error is instead of populating the list vertically, it gets appended as a group. Please suggest me on how to rectify this.

Comment: Are you then printing this somewhere?  Where is the code to display the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your JList, but rather your matcher logic.

If you always know your "types" are going to be within parenthesis, you can do the following.

```
// Declare lists
DefaultListModel<String> lista1 = new DefaultListModel<String>();
ArrayList<String> variableList = new ArrayList<String>();
JList<String> jList = new JList<String>();

String result = "type(t1, t2)";

// Get string within parenthesis
result = result.substring(result.indexOf('(') + 1, result.indexOf(')'));

// Split into elements
String[] types = result.split(",");

// For each, add to list if not duplicate
for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) 
 { 
    String type = types[i].trim();
    if (!variableList.contains(type))
    { 
        variableList.add(type);
        lista1.addElement(type);
    }
 }

jList.setModel(lista1);

// Add to frame/revalidate/repaint as needed
```

Also, parametrize your JList and DefaultListModel. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469945/java-warning-jlist-is-a-raw-type-references-must-be-parameterized)